# Issue with parsing json files

Tags: python, match, sys

I have a problem with the fonction. The fonction does not give me the right information

I have this

```
<function FHD at 0x7f52d72ceaa0>
<function FHD at 0x7f52d72ceaa0>
```

I look for this information

```
F1nd6zcHrcaJ6LnVsMMe8Ub_9fnC0gS9dhNFQ_ThInJVDkeJfooSSgxDgjiq6VVWx3OAT912O4q0LcTmJlKroFf63YEsqv2ytLr8q%2BTVlT4%3D-rD4Oo3s9FeXWjFOW2JU2VA%3D%3D
```

in this  files

```
,"vostf":{"FHD":"33CRwZHs7ZyMW8dTu9j3KjQkvwfmzhA%2BTvYpy5SJna4iyrWKYn_xUzq1srQOQuQlywNeROhRGNB0MC8yqO3Sj7PGb%2BZKTUqBEfZ4f83FNWI%3D-pUS3GCLfkr%2BN5jN%2BKGpxCQ%3D%3D.mp4?audioindex=0","HD":"F1nd6zcHrcaJ6LnVsMMe8Ub_9fnC0gS9dhNFQ_ThInJVDkeJfooSSgxDgjiq6VVWx3OAT912O4q0LcTmJlKroFf63YEsqv2ytLr8q%2BTVlT4%3D-rD4Oo3s9FeXWjFOW2JU2VA%3D%3D.mp4?audioindex=0","MOBILE":"%2BG4zTkYiUg3ADpg4cvqoywZxsXJLvoxEmIvolvRzz6vyYP_B2nTJNGx3teCdKKivxo_PgrDB_o3iFqfBFXY5qrW%2B25l9bXEk2lGRgFp4Ckc0ba6FE95mN%2Brevsj5FoS3-eg4EJWe_bE%2BcjLzc_dSpfw%3D%3D.mp4","SD":"rohgzlYg5krQOwShuYiEgi_LoZHcKk96kr2fPbHBDYmvfWqGnHKdCUuLISlNurkOBfsiAoPS3cXVIFRQ2cTpO3Jq6WklB7eAyUXCas2NfNM%3D-dEaZ85lb5fXeqOD40FOkOg%3D%3D.mp4?audioindex=0"}}

#RECUP QUALITE FHD
import re, os
def FHD(RFHD):
    mykey = open("/home/gaaara/adn/tmp/ajax.json", "r")
    for text in mykey:
        match = re.search('"FHD":"(.+?).mp4', text)
    if match:

        return  match.group(1)
#test
import sys
sys.path.append('files/')
from rez import FHD
oname = FHD
print oname
```

Comment: Do you want to parse JSON?

Comment: yes i parse a json to get information in my script

Comment: Do you know that [you don't have to do this yourself](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

Comment: do you realize it's **much** easier to parse your `.json` file with the `json` module than it is to write custom regexes that don't give the correct results?

Comment: yes i give the good value with the code i edited  :) I does not understand(include) why he(it) gives me not the good information with my modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's becasue you are assigning the function itself to the `oname` variable.you need to call the function and then assign the *return value* of that function to the variable.

You can do it like this, `oname = FHD()`. note the parenthesis.

I can see that you are using a function argument named `RFHD`.but you are not using it inside your function.you gonna have to pass some value to it or else your function call will be failed. something like, `oname = FHD('RFHD')`

As other have suggested, you can make your life easier by using the built-in json parsing lib.

Take a look at, [Parsing values from a JSON file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2835672/1189040).in your case, you have to use `data['vostf']['FHD']`

Comment: mm for the  json parsing lib. how to used this i dont no understand the demo in (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and on mirc Somebody give me this ` json.loads('{"x": 3}')` i dont no understand sorry im a debutent

Comment: and you have a idea for ini files to get the desired function in a principal script

Comment: @hideyoshi, I've updated my answer regarding the json parsing. i think it's better to ask a new question regarding the ini  file.there is a built-in function for that as well, [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

Comment: it works juste I want only the characters ` {"FHD":"33CRwZHs7ZyMW8dTu9j3KjQkvwfmzhA%2BTvYpy5SJna4iyrWKYn_xUzq1srQOQuQlywNeROhRGNB0MC8yqO3Sj7PGb%2BZKTUqBEfZ4f83FNWI%3D-pUS3GCLfkr%2BN5jN%2BKGpxCQ%3D%3D.mp4?audioindex=0` into the " "

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you meant. you want the all the parts including `{"FHD":` part ? or you meant you don't need all the parts after the file extension ? in that case you can use regex to get the relevant part. first get the 'FHD' value using `data['vostf']['FHD']` and then use your regex to get the filename from that string.

Comment: for me the regex is the best i have exactly That I need :)

Comment: @hideyoshi, the JSON specification includes things like escaping rules; no regex can perform unescaping -- it's not a powerful enough language to contain logic of that type -- so any regex-based JSON parser is **necessarily** broken and buggy. Also, your regex is actually broken: You aren't escaping the `.` (which, in regular expressions, mean "match any character") in `.mp4`, meaning that it would also treat `amp4` as the end of a filename.